# Creating a Case that has a custom visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a custom link on the home page that is used to create a new case. The link opens a custom visualforce page for the case object. I am trying to prepopulate a field called RequestedBy (lookup to user) with the user's name. My visualforce page uses an extension, which is just a query into the user object.  I am retrieving the user's name, but I the RequestedBy field is not being popluated with the name.

I tried by using `<apex:inputfield value="{!currentuser.name}"></apex:inputfield>` in my vf page, but that doesn't work.

```
public class UserExtension{ 
    public user currentuser{get;set;} 
    public UserExtension(ApexPages.StandardController cont){
        currentuser=new User(); 
        currentuser=[Select Id,Name,Email,Phone from User where Id=:userinfo.getuserId()]; 
    } 
}
```

Can someone please help me?
I'm trying to populate the Requested_By__C, User_Phone__C, and User_Email__C fields in my vforce form with the results from my query in the above controller.

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!Case.Requested_By__c}"></apex:inputfield>
<apex:inputfield value="{!Case.User_Phone__c}"></apex:inputfield>
<apex:inputfield value="{!Case.User_Email__c}"></apex:inputfield>
```

Comment: Could you also show the relevant parts of the controller extension?

Comment: @martin,  My controller is the below.                                                                                             
  public class UserExtension{
  public user currentuser{get;set;}
  public UserExtension(ApexPages.StandardController cont){

currentuser=new User();
currentuser=[Select Id,Name,Email,Phone from User where Id=:userinfo.getuserId()];
  } 
}

Comment: Thanks, I've edited that into the question and nominated your question for reopening.

Comment: Thanks @martin...I'll be sure to pose my question better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate the name of the user, you just need to refer the `RequestedBy` field.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Case.API_Name_of_RequestedBy_Field}" />
```

The `apex:inputField` will populate the Name of the lookup field.

As you are not using Case extension, to auto-populate the data from the User object and then create a case, do the following

```
public class UserExtension{ 
    public user currentuser{get;set;}
    public Case caseObject {get;set;}

    public UserExtension(ApexPages.StandardController cont){
        currentuser=new User(); 
        currentuser=[Select Id, Name, Email, Phone from User where id=:userinfo.getuserId()];
        caseObject = new Case();
        caseObject.Requested_By__c = currentuser.Id;
        caseObject.User_Phone__c = currentuser.Phone;
        caseObject.User_Email__c= currentuser.Email;
}
```

}

VF page:

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!caseObject.Requested_By__c}"></apex:inputfield>
<apex:inputfield value="{!caseObject.User_Phone__c}"></apex:inputfield>
<apex:inputfield value="{!caseObject.User_Email__c}"></apex:inputfield>
```

Comment: @Anika, When I do what you suggest, the page opens and the look up field is there, but the name of the user doesn't populate the field.                                                                    
<apex:inputField value="{!Case.Requested_By__c}" />

Comment: Is it Case Extension? Also, are you passing the id of the case record?

Comment: No, I am trying to create a new case with the use of a custom link. The link opens my vforce page, which has an extension that fires off a query against the user object.

Comment: You are not querying on the `Case` object. So, you will not get the value.

Comment: Sorry, I am not being clear. I"m trying to create a new case and auto-populate the requested by, email, and phone number fields on a custom vforce page layout. I use the a custom link on the home page to launch the vforce page, which is using the extension to query the user object and return the data I need.

Comment: With which values you want to auto-populate the data?

Comment: I have 3 fields, Requested by, Email, Phone.  I am trying to auto-populate them with the information of the user who is creating the case.

Comment: thank you for your help.  My fields get populated as I wanted.  Now I need to figure out how to save the record.